# datetime.strptime() operation receiving Tensorflow tensors instead of string

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to do operation datetime.strptime on Tensorflow tensors:

```
def convert_to_date(feat):
    return datetime.strptime(feat, DATETIME_DEFAULT_FORMAT).timestamp() if feat else np.nan

DATETIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
inputs = tf.constant(['2012-06-19 06:00', '2012-06-19 06:01', '2020-01-02 12:00'])

map_func = lambda feat: tf.py_function(func=convert_date, inp=[feat], Tout=tf.float32)
x = tf.map_fn(fn=map_func, elems=inputs)
```

I got an error because the argument of strptime() is a tensor, not a string:

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor
```

What is the workaround for this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If eager execution is an option, you can use the `numpy` method to evaluate the tensor, decode it to a string and call `datetime.strptime` on it:

```
def convert_to_date(feat):
    return datetime.strptime(feat.numpy().decode("utf-8"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").timestamp() if feat else np.nan
```

and then setting the output signature in the call to `map_fn`:

```
>>> inputs = tf.constant(['2012-06-19 06:00', '2012-06-19 06:01', '2020-01-02 12:00'])
>>> map_func = lambda feat: tf.py_function(func=convert_to_date, inp=[feat], Tout=tf.float32)
>>> tf.map_fn(fn=map_func, elems=inputs, fn_output_signature=tf.float32)
    <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([1.3400783e+09, 1.3400785e+09, 1.5779628e+09], dtype=float32)>
```

If eager execution is not an option (i.e, you want to call that function in a `tf.data.Dataset` or to use `tf.function`), then, you should consider a numpy function and [`tf.numpy_function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function):

```
def np_convert_to_timestamp(feat):
    unix_time = np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00')
    timestamps = (np.array(feat).astype(np.datetime64) - unix_time)/np.timedelta64(1,'s')
    return timestamps.astype(np.float32)
```

And an example of calling the function:

```
>>> inputs = tf.constant(['2012-06-19 06:00', '2012-06-19 06:01', '2020-01-02 12:00'])
>>> map_func = tf.function(lambda feat: tf.numpy_function(np_convert_to_timestamp, [feat], Tout=tf.float32))
>>> tf.map_fn(fn=map_func, elems=inputs, fn_output_signature=tf.float32)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([1.3400856e+09, 1.3400856e+09, 1.5779663e+09], dtype=float32)>
```